# Just installed a new chain but it took me 4 tries, is it safe?

Tags: shimano, chain

I just installed a new Shimano 105 11sp chain on my bike using a park tool chain tool to put in the pin. But I screwed it up 3 times . After each time, I popped out the pin and used a new pin (ended up using 4 pins). Is it safe?

I only ask because I didn't know if by pushing so many pins through the link I may have opened the link hole too much or something.

On the 4th time, I pushed the pin a little too much so the link was tight, so I rotated the chain tool around and gave it a 1/32 turn to push it back a quarter-hair.

**If you must know how the hell I did it wrong so many times:**

- time 1: Inserted the pin from wrong direction & and it was outside one of the jocky wheel tabs
- time 2: outside one of the jocky wheel tabs
- time 3: outside one of the jocky wheel tabs (yep, it was early and I seriously just popped out the pin and put a new one without fixing it)

Comment: What does 'outside one of the jocky wheel tabs' mean? Do you mean outer chain plates?

Comment: No, there are tabs at the jockey wheels on the derailleur that keep the chain from falling off the wheels. I didn't thread the chain through properly so it was riding on the tab and not the wheel

Comment: The tabs at the jockey wheel are part of the rear derailleur cage, bent over to keep the chain in.  I've made the same mistake but unscrewed the jockey wheels instead of breaking the chain.  On some RDs you don't have to complete remove the screws.

Comment: A broken chain isn't fun, but it's not among the most dangerous failures (the last 5 I saw were all on one big ride, no-one crashed but it's certainly possible as they tend to break under load).  It does however strand you.  If riding in the middle of nowhere, or riding hard close to other riders, are things you do, the answer may be rather different to if you commute a few km each way, passing several bike shops.  So this would be useful information

Comment: I did the thing with the jockey wheels tabs last week -- dumb!  The thing to do is to not re-break the chain in the same place, but break at least several links away from the last spot.

Comment: Another reason not to use pins but quick links right at the beginning. They've never let me down. Pins did!

Comment: On 11 speed, SRAM chains come with 1 time use links, and Shimano come with pins. I don't remember if the KMC links are reusable off the top of my head, but you can get connex links or whatever if you want to; its just an extra expense though.

Comment: Consider adding a quick link or two to your on-bike toolkit in case of breakage later.

Comment: @Batman Even Shimano now sell quick links. And Shimano chains also work with 'foreign' quick links. I always carry a spare KMC link with my repair kit.

Comment: @Carel - didn't know that shimano sold quick links now. In this case though, aside from the connex (and possibly kmc) links, the shimano / sram links wouldn't (shouldn't?) have helped since they're one time use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never break the chain at the connecting pin. Once a connecting pin is in there, it should not be removed.

Removing a regular rivet enlarges the holes in the chain plates slightly. A connecting pin has a slightly greater diameter than a regular rivet so it fits properly. When you push out the connecting pin the holes get enlarged slightly *again*, so now a new connecting ping is slightly too small.

So you have weakened the chain and run a increased risk of breaking it. You'll have to decide if you want to take on that risk. Personally, I would fix the chain for peace of mind.

If you want to fix it you have a couple of choices:

1. Replace the damaged chain links with new links from the small length of chain left over when you shortened the new chain, using two new connecting pins, and being extra careful to not screw it up this time.
2. Replace the damaged outer chain links with a Shimano Quick Link. Beware that most quick links are one-time use so make sure the chain is routed properly before completing installation.

I recommend #2

BTW, if you threaded the chain through the derailleur cage incorrectly, you can remove one cage side plate instead of re-breaking the chain.

Comment: Sometimes you can disassemble the derailer, sometimes not.

Comment: @DanielRHicks if you do disassemble the derailleur to re-thread the chain, make sure to use loctite thread locker on the jockey wheel screws, otherwise the derailleur could spontaneously disassemble itself in the near future.